# Docker volumes not mounting

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am using this docker image ( https://hub.docker.com/r/karai17/lapis-centos/~/dockerfile/ ) and the following docker run script and it's not setting up my volumes. When I open the container with bash, both `/var/www` and `/var/data` are empty.

```
docker run -dti -p 8888:2808
-v "C:\Users\karai\Documents\GitHub\project\data:/var/data"
-v "C:\Users\karai\Documents\GitHub\project\www:/var/www"
--name project
karai17/lapis-centos:latest
```

This was working just the other day, the only changes I've made to the Docker image was to add a few more Lua Rocks. All of the data is 100% definitely there, so I am not sure what is going on.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what happened but after doing a factory reset of Docker for Windows, the issue has been resolved.